# RESTful Android client with @pathparm server based on Jersey

Tags: java, android, client, jersey, restful-url

I have problem to post file on Jersey database with more than one @pathparams (without @pathparam tests, works!!).

The server code is:

```
@POST
@Path("visit_add_image/{key}/{idvisita}/{body}/{img}/{img2}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String visit_add_image(  @FormDataParam("key")String key, 
                                @FormDataParam("idvisita")Integer idvisita,
                                @FormDataParam("body")String body,
                                @FormDataParam("img")InputStream img,
                                @FormDataParam("img")FormDataContentDisposition imgDetail,
                                @FormDataParam("img2")InputStream img2,
                                @FormDataParam("img2")FormDataContentDisposition imgDetail2) throws SQLException{
    return "";
}
```

And the client is something like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url../user/visit_add_image/11/111/112");


        FileBody fileContent= new FileBody(new File("/Users/Achron/Downloads/sun.jpg"));
        FileBody fileContent2 = new FileBody(new File("/Users/Achron/Downloads/sun.jpg"));
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        reqEntity.addPart("img", fileContent);
        reqEntity.addPart("img2", fileContent2);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println("file "+response.toString()+""+" e stato inviato al server");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And not working because the answer of server is 404. Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to a different URL than your `@Path` on the resource, which is why you are receiving a 404.  Make sure you have the correct number of path elements in your `HttpPost` request.